# Cómo poner una condición para que tome la primera vocal de una palabra

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp

Estoy buscando la forma de que en apellido2 cuando coloque un nombre como jhonatan me tome la primera letra y la primera vocal, no sé si me puedan ayudar.

```
public string CrearRfc(EntRFC p)
{
   string name = p.Nombres.Substring(0, 1).Replace("Ñ", "X").Replace(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+ á,é,í,ó,ú","X");
   string ap1 = p.Paterno.Substring(0, 2).Replace("Ñ", "X").Replace(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+ á,é,í,ó,ú", "X");
   string ap2 = p.Materno.Substring(0, 1).Replace("Ñ", "X").Replace(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+ á,é,í,ó,ú", "X");
   string date = p.FechaNacimiento.ToString("yy-MM-dd").Replace("-", "");
   
   p.Rfc = ap1 + ap2 + name + date;
}
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo con el resultado esperado

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string CrearRfc(EntRFC p)
    {
        string name = p.Nombres.Substring(0, 1).Replace("Ñ", "X").Replace(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+ á,é,í,ó,ú", "X");
        string ap1 = p.Paterno.Substring(0, 1).Replace("Ñ", "X").Replace(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+ á,é,í,ó,ú", "X");
        ap1 += p.Paterno.Replace("Ñ", "X").Replace(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+ á,é,í,ó,ú", "X")[p.Paterno.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' })];
        string ap2 = p.Materno.Substring(0, 1).Replace("Ñ", "X").Replace(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+ á,é,í,ó,ú", "X");
        string date = p.FechaNacimiento.ToString("yy-MM-dd").Replace("-", "");

        return ap1 + ap2 + name + date;
    }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).